# Pytorch Chatbot Tutorial problem: How can I solve List Index Out of Range

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, chatbot

I’m new to pytorch and have been following the many tutorials available.
But, When I did The [CHATBOT TUTORIAL](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/chatbot_tutorial.html?highlight=chatbot%20tutorial) is not work.

Like the figure below

[image]

What should I do and what is causing this?

Comment: Please do not put your error messages in the image, but rather paste the text to the actual post instead.

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but I hit this same error at this line before on this same tutorial.  I am also running on 3.6 on Windows, had no issues loading PyTorch or running anything with CUDA.  The issue for me was in the data.

It was because there was a blank line somewhere in the source data, so when it went to split the words in the list for that function, it threw this error - there were no words to split.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You can help improve your post by providing the *specific* error you saw, and showing an **example** of how you corrected the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Windows? Currently most Pytorch tutorial requires Pytorch 1.0 which is currently unavailable on Windows, I'm trying it in a different OS.

Will edit the answer as soon as I get it running on Ubuntu 18.

Comment: Yes,i run it on windows, but I import torch without any question. 

python 3.6 　package: pip,CUDA:9.0 it seems some data processing have question.Because Errormessage show:IndexError: list index out of range                                                         
 
I'm trying it in a different OS. "Will edit the answer as soon as I get it running on Ubuntu 18. "    Ah,   It was exhilarating,  I will try it as soon as possible.
the error seems happens in :
def filterPair(p):
def filterPairs(pairs):
I am very confused about this.

Answer (score 0):

```
def filter_pair(self, p):
    try:
        return len(p[0].split(' ')) < self.MAX_LENGTH and len(p[1].split(' '))<\ self.MAX_LENGTH
    except:
        return False
```

This is because some of pairs are empty list

Comment: Thanks, But the corpus are cornell movie-dialogs corpus.Corpus <https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~cristian/Cornell_Movie-Dialogs_Corpus.html>__ is a rich dataset of movie character dialog:

220,579 conversational exchanges between 10,292 pairs of movie characters
9,035 characters from 617 movies
304,713 total utterances                                                    I am not  understanding of the empty list in training data,but it showed Start preparing training data ...
Reading lines...
Read 442563 sentence pairs

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the way the lines are read in resulting in blank lines. You can get over the problem rather crudely by filtering out blank lines. Here is such a crude solution in the readVocs routine.

```
# Read query/response pairs and return a voc object
def readVocs(datafile, corpus_name):
    print("Reading lines...")
    # Read the file and split into lines
    lines = open(datafile, encoding='utf-8').\
        read().strip().split('\n')
    #Now on windows you seem to get alternate blank lines so filter them out.
    lines2=[]
    for l in lines:
        if len(l)>0:
            lines2.append(l)
    #And as a check just print the first 10
    for index, line in enumerate(lines2[:10]):
        print(index,' - ',line)

    # Split every line into pairs and normalize
    pairs = [[normalizeString(s) for s in l.split('\t')] for l in lines2]
    voc = Voc(corpus_name)
    return voc, pair
```

Comment: I tried the above with the tutorial mentioned and it runs all the way through quite happily on Windows with Torch version 0.4.1